# Точность модели машинного обучения

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, точность

При 5-кратной кроссвалидации точность регрессии (коэффициент детерминации r^2) низкая на последнем разбиении.

Что это означает? При обучении на всем наборе данных качество обучения падает? Или это не имеет значения?

Значения: 0.29, 0.05, 0.36, 0.18, -1.31
Среднее: -0.08346647029663619
Это значения при выходном столбце верхней границы заработной платы (там данные не такие качественные, как нижняя граница, так как чаще пропущены)
На нижней границе r2 около 48%, что меня вполне устраивает.

Стоит ли при таких значениях обучать для дальнейшего использования не на всем наборе данных, а на 1 и 3 части набора данных, где точность выше?

Набор данных - вакансии с hh.ru. Цель - прогнозирование заработной платы.

37 000 записей, 29 столбцов: опыт, ключевой навык, должность, работодатель, нижняя и верхняя граница заработной платы, специализация, профессиональная область (эти поля закодированы label encoding); город (Киров, Москва, СПб), график и тип занятости закодированы one hot encoding.

Данные не масштабировала, так как градиентный бустинг не чувствителен к масштабированию.
Сложности модели должно быть достаточно, так как на обучающем наборе данных точность около 70-80%. Если я правильно понимаю, то модель переобучается.

Ссылка на набор данных: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QJZAYyXIXcrMgzet8SUC31MzV5dHODcv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: если от того, что обучаете на всем или на двух/третих набора результаты сильно отличаются, значит либо набор данных подготовлен неверно (мало данных, или они были отсортированы). Либо просто неверно считаете свои коэффициенты (как было сказано ниже)

Comment: Да у вас и на втором фолде качество не фонтан. Да и на хороших фолдах качество не так, чтобы супер. Я бы на вашем месте поразбирался, что у вас вообще с данными. И какая у вас собственно модель? Может модели не хватает сложности. Или, например, у вас простая модель, а данные не нормализованы. Или опять же модель простая и есть выбросы, которые модели сильно мешают и их надо бы выкинуть. Просто выкидывать целые "плохие" фолды данных - ну, это перебор, я не уверен, что ваша модель научится хорошему если вы будете так разбазаривать данные. **Know your data** прежде всего. Изучите ваши данные.

Comment: В общем, лучше будет, если вы приложите к вопросу ваши данные, чтобы было о чём разговаривать. Пока это такое "лечение по фотографии". Симптомы видно и можно о чём-то догадываться, но наверняка сказать вряд ли возможно, не видя самих данных.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавила пояснения и ссылку на набор данных. Буду благодарна за ответ. То есть при правильно подготовленных данных плохие результаты на некоторых фолдах не портят всю модель?
И я использую r2, для социологических данных некоторые считают точность 25% приемлемой

Comment: Ну в принципе может быть такая ситуация, что данные вообще плохо поддаются моделям машинного обучения. Тогда и такой скор считается хорошим, да. Я позже посмотрю, по-нормальному нужно хоть какой-то EDA сделать для начала, а для этого нужно время. Так то мне и самому интересно, так что обязательно посмотрю. Но позже.

Comment: Так. А хотя бы какие фичи тут категориальные - вы модели указывали? У вас их много ведь. Хорошо бы ещё код приложить, которым вы кросс-валидацию собственно делали. Какие параметры были у бустинга?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так вот навскидку если, у вас проблема с выбросами в таргете. Есть какое-то количество данных, в которых отношение верхней границы к нижней слишком большое (2, 10 и даже 50 раз). Если выкинуть какое-то количество их этих выбросов, то картина становится гораздо лучше. Какое конкретно соотношение выбрать для отсечения - решать вам. Я выбрал для примера соотношение 3, от него и выше это примерно получается 2.5% ваших данных, на мой взгляд это небольшая жертва.

```py
print((df.salary_to/df.salary_from < 3).value_counts(normalize=True))
df_selected = df[df.salary_to/df.salary_from < 3]
X = df_selected[feature_columns]
y = df_selected.salary_to
model.fit(X, y)
print(r2_score(y, model.predict(X)))
print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='r2'))
```

Вывод:

```
True     0.975505
False    0.024495
dtype: float64
0.9147364058539751
[0.35825282 0.45682105 0.43133096 0.41867005 0.44403997]
```

У меня модель была `RandomForestRegressor`, но это не важно, на исходных ваших данных он показывал примерно ту же картину по фолдам, что и ваша модель.

P.S. Другой вариант, и при этом даже не нужно ничего выкидывать из данных - это взять логарифм от таргета. Но при этом я не совсем уверен, как тогда трактовать скор. И нужно не забывать брать потом экспоненту от предсказания в конце всего процесса.

```py
X = df[feature_columns]
y = np.log(df.salary_to)
model.fit(X, y)
print(r2_score(y, model.predict(X)))
print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='r2'))
```

Вывод:

```
0.9205070404891004
[0.45175607 0.46596345 0.48481266 0.4853811  0.4781465 ]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что при кросс-валидации точность такая: [0.35825282 0.45682105 0.43133096 0.41867005 0.44403997], но при обучении на всем наборе данных такая: 0.9147364058539751?
То есть точность на фолдах совершенно не отражает точность всей модели?

Comment: r2_score(y, model.predict(X)) получается эта строка обучает на всех данных и проверяет точность на этих же строках из датасета?

Comment: Кажется значение 0.9147364058539751 - точность на обучающем наборе данных, а не на тестовом. Цифры, которые приводила я, были на тестовом (валидационном). Не вижу смысла гнаться за точностью на обучающем наборе, если при этом тестовый страдает

Comment: Да, эта цифра, возможно, лишняя, но степень обучения на обучающем наборе я всё-равно обычно смотрю. Во-первых полезно посмотреть, что модель в принципе чему-то учится. Во-вторых, видно контраст между обучением и тестом, значит данные не однозначные. Ну в общем это так, для справки, не в этом суть.

Comment: Для меня как раз таки суть. Нужно понять что на самом деле является точностью модели для прогнозирования. Является ли среднее значение при кроссвалидации точностью для всей модели. Спасибо за ответы

Comment: Кросс-валидация - хороший метод. Можно попробовать с разным количеством фолдов, не только с 5, а скажем 3, 10, 20 фолдов. Но вообще это вопрос не такой простой, всегда могут попасться отдельные плохо предсказываемые сэмплы. Я бы их отдельно выявил и изучил. Иногда даже делают классификатор для выявления таких образцов и отдельную модель для предсказания на них. А так всё же любая метрика на наборе сэмплов - это средняя температура по больнице.